# Linear Independence in Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $F = \mathbb{R}$, $k = {0,1,2...}$ and 
$f_k: [-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_{k}(t) = t^k$

Show that the set of vectors $f_{k}(k)$ is linearly independent in $F$.

I try this:
We need to show that $a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2 + ... + a_nt^n =0\Rightarrow a_i=0$ for $i = \{1,2,...n\}$

I took $a_0 = a_1 = -a_2 = -a_3$ and $a_i=0$ for $i = \{4,5,...n\}$ to get $a_0 + a_1t + a_2t^2 + ... + a_nt^n = 0$ without all $a_i$ being $0$. So they are linearly dependant right? 

Eg: $1 + t - t^2 - t^3 = 0$ is true for all $t = [-1,1]$

Comment: Recall that an algebraic equation of degree $n$ has at most $n$ solutions.

Comment: The question as currently written doesn't make much sense, and your solution doesn't match it. You said the goal is to "show that the set of vectors $f_k(k)$ is linearly independent in $F$". Yes, $f_k(k)$ are elements of $F=\mathbb{R}$ (each $f_k(k)$ is just a number), but then what is the ground field -- linearly independent ***over what?*** But in your solution you're using **functions** $f_k(t)$, not  **numbers** $f_k(k)$. These functions are **NOT** elements of $F$. It would make sense to say "$f_k(t)$ are linearly independent over $F$", but that's a whole different question.

Comment: Also, the claim that "$1+t−t^2−t^3=0$ is true for all $t=[−1,1]$" is false (not to mention wrong notation -- it must be $t\in[−1,1]$, not "$t=[−1,1]$"). For example, try plugging in $t=0$. Anyways, please clarify what the question actually is.

Comment: I made a mistake in understanding the notations. I made a mistake in assuming that [-1,1] was {-1,1} and hence I made the wrong claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show that $f_0,f_1,\ldots,f_n$ are linearly independent, then you show that $a_0f_0(t)+\cdots+a_nf_n(t)=0$ **for all** $t\in[-1,1]$. The function $a_0f_0(t)+\cdots+a_nf_n$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$, and thus has at most $n$ roots as long as it is not the zero function.

> Suppose $a_i\neq 0$ for some $1\leq i\leq n$, then $a_it^i=0$ would hold for infinitely many $t$. This is of course a contradiction because this equation must have finitely many solutions by the argument in the previous paragraph. Therefore we must have $a_i=0$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$.